# use variable to select table in MSSQL Database

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to use a variable in the following statement to select the needed table in the database ... say setting variable %table%

```
sqlcmd -S .\database -U sa -P password -d %DATABASE% -Q "select * from "%table& -s "," -o "c:\save\info.csv"
```

trying to get a list of all columns and data from that table > but not sure how to implement %table% in the above code

Trying to do this in .bat ( Batch ) format ...

Comment: I expect this to work: `sqlcmd -S .\database -U sa -P password -d %DATABASE% -Q "select * from %table%" -s "," -o "c:\save\info.csv"`

Comment: Thank you that was helpful now I just need to find a way to list all tables so I can select one ... Thank you for your help truly appreciated I wasn't sure I could use a variable inside quotes ... but I now see you can